# Stream file uploaded with Express.js through gm to eliminate double write

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphicsmagick

I'm using `Express.js` and have a route to upload images that I then need to resize.  Currently I just let `Express` write the file to disk (which I think uses `node-formidable` under the covers) and then resize using `gm` (http://aheckmann.github.com/gm/) which writes a second version to disk.

```
gm(path)
  .resize(540,404)
  .write(dest, function (err) { ... });
```

I've read that you can get a hold of the `node-formidable` file stream before it writes it to disk, and since `gm` can accept a stream instead of just a path, I should be able to pass this right through eliminating the double write to disk.

I think I need to override `form.onPart` but I'm not sure where (should it be done as `Express` middleware?) and I'm not sure how to get a hold of `form` or what exactly to do with the `part`.  This is the code skeleton that I've seen in a few places:

```
form.onPart = function(part) {
    if (!part.filename) { form.handlePart(part); return; }

    part.on('data', function(buffer) {

    });
    part.on('end', function() {

    }
}
```

Can somebody help me put these two pieces together?  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on the right track by rewriting `form.onPart`. Formidable writes to disk by default, so you want to act before it does.

Parts themselves are Streams, so you can pipe them to whatever you want, including `gm`. I haven't tested it, but this makes sense based on the documentation:

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm;
form.onPart = function (part) {
  if (!part.filename) return this.handlePart(part);

  gm(part).resize(200, 200).stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('my/new/path/to/img.png'));
  });
};
```

As for the middleware, I'd copypaste the `multipart` middleware from Connect/Express and add the `onPart` function to it: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/multipart.html

It'd be a lot nicer if `formidable` didn't write to disk by default or if it took a flag, wouldn't it? You could send them an issue.

Comment: Thank you! This got me 95% of the way there. My last problem is that `gm` is async and so the form parsing returns before the resize is actually complete (meaning the url I had back to the client isn't any good yet). Is there a way to let `formidable` know when the `part` handling is actually complete?

Comment: Actually, I just ended up handling this on the client instead - works out better that way.  Thanks again!

Comment: stdout is a Stream. That's why you can pipe() it to a file WriteStream. And that means it has an "end" event you can listen to. Just do stdout.on('end', fn) and that's when you can tell the client the job is done.