# What "streams and pipe-capable" means in pkgcloud in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, pkgcloud

My issue is to get image uploading to amazon working.
I was looking for a solution that doesnt save the file on the server and **then** upload it to Amazon.

Googling I found [pkgcloud](https://github.com/nodejitsu/pkgcloud#storage) and on the README.md it says:

> Special attention has been paid so that methods are streams and
>   pipe-capable.

Can someone explain what that means and if it is what I am looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yupp, that means you've found the right kind of `s3` library.

What it means is that this library exposes "streams". Here is the API that defines a stream: http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Using node's stream interface, you can pipe any readable stream (in this case the POST's body) to any writable stream (in this case the S3 upload).

Here is an example of how to pipe a file upload directly to another kind of library that supports streams: [How to handle POSTed files in Express.js without doing a disk write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832884/how-to-handle-posted-files-in-express-js-without-doing-a-disk-write)

EDIT: Here is an example

```
var pkgcloud = require('pkgcloud'),
      fs = require('fs');

var s3client = pkgcloud.storage.createClient({ /* ... */ });

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  var s3upload = s3client.upload({
    container: 'a-container',
    remote: 'remote-file-name.txt'
  })

  // pipe the image data directly to S3
  req.pipe(s3upload);      
});
```

EDIT: To finish answering the questions that came up in the chat:

`req.end()` will automatically call `s3upload.end()` thanks to stream magic. If the OP wants to do anything else on req's end, he can do so easily: `req.on('end', res.send("done!"))`

Comment: will it be saved in memory then?

Comment: It won't be "saved" but it will stay in memory during the `pipe()`, yes. :)

Comment: argh. you think that is there any "better way" to do file uploading to amazon?

Comment: hehe. that's a completely different question ;) but here is an alternative, that you might think is "better": http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html

Comment: but to clarify: using the code above, your users will be able to upload large files, since only parts of the files will ever be in memory at a time. does that help?

Comment: hold on, I dont understand on thing. How do I close the post request if there is no req.end ? and where do I take the file the user uploaded?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24044/discussion-between-rdrey-and-haskellguy)